# Symfony inject EntityManager in LogoutListener

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x

Using Symfony 3.4, I need to do persist user before logout, so I've implemented the following listener:

```
<?php
namespace c975L\UserBundle\Listeners;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use c975L\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof User) {
            $user->setLatestSignout(new \DateTime());
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I have autowired in `services.yml`

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
    c975L\UserBundle\Listeners\:
        resource: '../../Listeners/*'
```

but I receive the following compilation error

> Compile Error: ContainerNxlf3ac\appDevDebugProjectContainer::load(): Failed opening required '/.../var/cache/dev/ContainerNxlf3ac/getLogoutlistener2Service.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

It looks like I have to alias the service but I can't manage to do so...

I have the same result when using `parent::__construct();`

Error doesn't appear if `__construct()` is removed but then `$this->em` is not defined...

**[EDIT - Added firewall part]**

```
security.yml

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|fonts|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: c975_l_userbundle
        form_login:
            login_path: user_signin
            check_path: user_signin
            default_target_path: user_dashboard
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            secure: true
        anonymous:    true
        logout_on_user_change: true
        logout:
            path: user_signout
            handlers: [c975L\UserBundle\Listeners\Logoutlistener]
```

Comment: I have not seen that sort of error message before and the way you are specifying the Listeners directory seems a bit strange.  Not saying to won't work but it is unusual.  You are running in development mode?  You get this error message while running bin/console?  Start by verifying you have the EntotyManagerInterface defined (it should be) with "bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep EntityManager"

Comment: The 2 in getLogoutlistener2Service is also a bit suspicious.  Though I suppose you may have trying different things in an effort to get past the error and perhaps lost track.

Comment: Did you try a `bin/console debug:autowiring` to check if your service is autowired correctly? Also `bin/console debug:container <class name>` to see if the service is stored in the container correctly?

Comment: @Cerad what do you mean by strange specification of Listeners directory? Yes it runs in dev mode. No the error displayed on the web page. and yes the EntityManagerInterface is defined. For the 2, I don't know why it's there but it's in the error message

Comment: @dbrumann for `bin/console debug:container LogoutListener` I can see the information for related service and it is autowired correctly. Thansk for these commands I didn't know about.

Comment: Please update your question with the firewalls portion of security.yaml.  I tried a simple test case with logout: handlers end got a single getLogoutListenerService.php file in the cache directory as expected.  That fact that you got 2 implies that something is confused.  Actually, before you do anything, delete the entire var/cache directory.  That will ensure there is no old stuff messing you up.

Comment: @Cerad, I've updated and yes before posting I've deleted the cache folder but you're right to suggest it.

Comment: I have also only one file `getLogoutListenerService.php` with the following content `return $this->services['c975L\UserBundle\Listeners\LogoutListener'] = new \c975L\UserBundle\Listeners\LogoutListener(${($_ = isset($this->services['doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']) ? $this->services['doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'] : $this->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService()) && false ?: '_'});` which looks good

Comment: Very puzzling especially since you only have the one real firewall defined.  If you had multiple firwalls then I could understan it.  Take a look at getSecurity_LogoutListener_MainService.php and verify it is calling the getLogoutListener2Service.  If not then search the entire container directory and see where it is coming from.  c975L is your own code?  Not trying to use some obsolete third party code?

Comment: I can't find any reference to the "2" file, everything calls the file without "2" which is coherent with the message trying to open a non-existing file. Yes c975L is my own code. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Well something is trying to load the silly thing.  Search for it from your projects home directory.  Maybe some weird vendor interaction.  And make sure you are in the project you think you are.  Stranger things have happened.

Comment: argh... I've found! when I did the search mentionned above, it was case sensitive, I did another search only with `2Service` and found it in the file you've mentionned. The problem was in the firewall part, it was `listener` in place of `Listener` with uppercase L... Thanks for your time! If you have more spare time, I would be interested in the "strange" Listeners specification part.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.

Comment: "Strange" was perhaps a bit strong.  Typically a bundle loads it's own services via it's own DI extension.  So you would not see any references to it in app/config/services.yml.  But obviously it works so don't worry about it.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs as it was purely a typo problem, I was thinking adding the solution to the problem, but I did as you said.

Comment: @Cerad, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Cerad I came back to your explanation and better read it. The ‘services.yml’ is well located in my bundle DI part, not in the app one. Just to remove any doubt ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the firewall part. It was a mistake using a "l" (lowercase) in place of a "L" (uppercase) for `LogoutListener` name. Setting the following worked.

```
handlers: [c975L\UserBundle\Listeners\LogoutListener]
```

**[EDIT]**
There was a bug, that has been solved by https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26355

Comment: Just wanted to add that starting with 4.0 you get a much cleaner service does not exist message.  In earlier versions the container tried to be case insensitive leading to issues such as this.

Comment: Yes I saw it's marked as deprecated in 3.3. I had to finish the bundle (because linked to others and live websites) and now I can move to 4. Thanks again for your time and help.